# Android notification sound override

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have made an android taxi hailing app like Uber. When a request is going to the driver, it is showing as a notification like any other notification of whatsapp and message with the default popup notification sound. I need the notification sound to ring for 15 to 20 seconds instead of the pop up sound . How do I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

try to set the ring tone file which have a length of 15 to 20 sec

```
//App.appInstance --> Application class instance
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + App.appInstance.getPackageName() + "/" + 
             R.raw.notification_sound); 

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(App.appInstance, "")
                                     .setSound(uri)
```

place the sound file in the raw folder

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this) 
            ................setSound(soundUri)......... 
            .build();
```